# Why is this query returning more values then it should

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT username, user_status
FROM users
JOIN relationships ON users.user_id = relationships.user_two_id
WHERE relationships.user_one_id = $1
   OR relationships.user_two_id = $1
  AND relationships.relationship_status = 1
```

The query in question is above; what I'm trying to do is use the users ID 
 verify if the user(s) are friends or not based on the '1' that would be present if they're friends.

EXPECTED:
return users status if they ARE friends

ACTUAL:
returning extra duplicates of the user whom I am performing the query for- so If my username is bob and I perform this query i'm seeing bob multiple times when I should not even see him once.

Example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
user_id bigserial UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(70),
username VARCHAR(30)UNIQUE,
dob  INTEGER,
country VARCHAR(30),
province VARCHAR(30),
city VARCHAR(30),
date TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE relationships(
record bigserial UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
user_one_id bigserial REFERENCES users(user_id),
user_two_id bigserial REFERENCES users(user_id),
relationship_status INTEGER,
date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME zone
);
```

Comment: There are "duplicate" rows in the *relationships* source table for `user_two_id`. So why is the query selecting 'unexpected' rows? Well, look at the *data*..

Comment: It may be useful to consider that `WHERE relationships.user_one_id = $1 OR relationships.user_two_id = $1 AND relationships.relationship_status = 1` is parsed as `WHERE relationships.user_one_id = $1 OR (relationships.user_two_id = $1 AND relationships.relationship_status = 1)` (note the parenthesis; AND has a higher precedence than OR).

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Why did you tag both?

Comment: @user2864740 I deleted the duplicate rows from the table prior to posting this question there are no duplicate relationships currently. Do you have any recommendations how make this query more robust or how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter most backend devs deal with mysql at some point or rather, same logic as it's pretty common thus exposing my question to more eyes. The query I am performing is in Postgres

Comment: So do *not* tag is [mysql] just to get more eyes.

Comment: I also noticed through experimenting that it will return the proper number or occurrences but, it return the username as "bob" ( me when i'm performing this query) when my userID is in the user_one_id; i'm unsure at this point how to always return the friends name and never mine in this scenario.

Comment: Neither your query nor your explanation are clear to me. You speak of "they", but there is only `$1` in the query. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Was a one liner and pretty intrinsic when ran; SELECT DISTINCT username, user_status ....